# SharePoint 2016 Installation Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, 2016, farm-admin

I am installing SharePoint 2016 and came across the below error . 
Can any one help me in knowing what might be the issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to create configuration database` usually denote to misconfiguration in database server side, So I suggest to

- Check the log to can trace where is the main issue.
- Make sure `Max Degree Parallelism` set to **1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the WCF Data Services component, go to Program and Features and click on Microsoft WCF Data Service 5.6 Tools. Now click change, when the window appears for Modify setup run the Repair opition.

Then re-try the install of SharePoint.

I have had this happen if the component was installed manually rather than through the pre-requiste installer.

Comment: Dears,
I tried both the ways ,But I found no luck .

Comment: The account you are using has the correct permissions on the DB?